# Why is the C# Task Parallel Library code slower than a normal for loop?

Tags: c#, performance, task-parallel-library

I'm wondering why the parallel code isn't faster than a normal `for` loop with this code:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static int count = 0;

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        int range = 1000000;
        Stopwatch sp = new Stopwatch ();
        sp.Start ();
        Parallel.For (0, range, (i) => {
            count = count + i;
            Console.WriteLine ("Current sum is " + count);
        });
        sp.Stop ();
        Console.WriteLine ("time to add was " + sp.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadLine ();

        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch ();
        s.Start ();
        for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) {
            count = count + i;
            Console.WriteLine ("Current sum is " + count);
        }
        s.Stop ();
        Console.WriteLine ("time to add was " + s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've migrated your question to Stack Overflow because you are asking "Why does my code behave this way?" rather than "How can I improve my code?"

Comment: Aside from anything else, your code isn't thread-safe. You're mutating shared state in an unsafe manner in multiple threads. You may well not get the same result anyway. Beyond that, the vast majority of the time in your code is going to be spent in `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: The code inside Parallel.For isn't really doing anything so you are only measuring the overhead of PLINQ.

Comment: due to the overhead of spawning and disposing threads

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: It would be nice to know why this was downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get more accurate results, remove the calls to `Console.WriteLine` inside both loops. You will still see that parallel loop is slower, because of the reasons stated in the question comments.

To get a better feel for why that is, use instead an overload of `Parallel.For` from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781401(v=vs.110).aspx) and set the property `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to 4 (allow max 4 concurrent operations) or -1 (no restrictions) and the parallel for loop is slower, as expected, because of the thread handling overhead. Now set `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to 1, meaning only 1 thread will be handling the loop operation. Should result into similar timings now right?

Now the results are closer, but the parallel loop is still slower. It is, **i think**,  because the parallel loop still has to handle threading and interact with the `TaskScheduler` somehow, where the normal loop does not at all.

I hope this answer gives you some more insight.